# Java 8 collect and change the format of the result

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have the data structre called `MyPojo` which has fields called `time`, `name` and `timetaken` (all are in Strings). I'm trying to do some grouping as follows:

```
    List<MyPojo> myPojos = Arrays.asList(
        new MyPojo("2017", "ABC", "30"),
        new MyPojo("2017", "ABC", "20"),
        new MyPojo("2016", "ABC", "25"),
        new MyPojo("2017", "XYZ", "40")
    );

    Map<String, Map<String, Double>> resultMap = myPojos.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyPojo::getName,
            Collectors.groupingBy(MyPojo::getTime,
                Collectors.averagingDouble(MyPojo::getTimeTakenAsDouble))));
```

Please note that I've a method called `getTimeTakenAsDouble` to convert the`timetaken` string to double value.

This results as follows:

```
    {ABC={2017=25.0, 2016=25.0}, XYZ={2017=40.0}}
```

However, my frontend developer wanted the data either in the following format:

```
    {ABC={2017=25.0, 2016=25.0}, XYZ={2017=40.0, 2016=0.0}}
```

or

```
    [
            {
                    "time": "2017",
                    "name": "ABC",
                    "avgTimeTaken": 25.0
            },
            {
                    "time": "2017",
                    "name": "XYZ",
                    "avgTimeTaken": 40.0
            },
            {
                    "time": "2016",
                    "name": "ABC",
                    "avgTimeTaken": 25.0
            },
            {
                    "time": "2016",
                    "name": "XYZ",
                    "avgTimeTaken": 0.0
            }
    ]
```

I'm thinking to perform iterations on the `resultMap` and prepare the 2nd format. I'm trying to perform the iteration again on the `resultMap`. Is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's pretty interesting what you are trying to achieve. It's like you are trying to do some sort of logical `padding`. The way I've done it is to use `Collectors.collectingAndThen`. Once the result is there - I simply pad it with needed data.

Notice that I'm using `Sets.difference` from `guava`, but that can easily be put into a static method. Also there are additional operations performed.

So I assume your `MyPojo` looks like this:

```
 static class MyPojo {

    private final String time;

    private final String name;

    private final String timetaken;

    public MyPojo(String time, String name, String timetaken) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
        this.timetaken = timetaken;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getTimetaken() {
        return timetaken;
    }

    public static double getTimeTakenAsDouble(MyPojo pojo) {
        return Double.parseDouble(pojo.getTimetaken());
    }
}
```

And input data that I've checked against is :

```
 List<MyPojo> myPojos = Arrays.asList(
            new MyPojo("2017", "ABC", "30"),
            new MyPojo("2017", "ABC", "20"),
            new MyPojo("2016", "ABC", "25"),
            new MyPojo("2017", "XYZ", "40"),
            new MyPojo("2018", "RDF", "80"));
```

Here is the code that does what you want:

```
 Set<String> distinctYears = myPojos.stream().map(MyPojo::getTime).collect(Collectors.toSet());

 Map<String, Map<String, Double>> resultMap = myPojos.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyPojo::getName,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                            Collectors.groupingBy(MyPojo::getTime,
                                    Collectors.averagingDouble(MyPojo::getTimeTakenAsDouble)),
                            map -> {
                                Set<String> localYears = map.keySet();
                                SetView<String> diff = Sets.difference(distinctYears, localYears);
                                Map<String, Double> toReturn = new HashMap<>(localYears.size() + diff.size());
                                toReturn.putAll(map);
                                diff.stream().forEach(e -> toReturn.put(e, 0.0));
                                return toReturn;
                            }
                    )));
```

Result of that would be:

```
{ABC={2016=25.0, 2018=0.0, 2017=25.0}, 
 RDF={2016=0.0, 2018=80.0, 2017=0.0}, 
 XYZ={2016=0.0, 2018=0.0, 2017=40.0}}
```

Comment: What is `distinctYears` here?

Comment: @VimalrajSelvam my bad. just added

Comment: This is a good approach. Though when I needed to do this, I've done it the other way round: I first created a map and filled it with all *zero* entries for each possible group, and then used a collector (either `groupingBy` or `toMap`) with a custom map supplier `() -> myMapWithZeroes`.